# how do I find royalty-free music for web videos?

Tags: video, website, youtube, copyright

I would like to add background music to web videos.  I do not want to violate any copyright laws.  How can I find instrumental music that I can use as background for my web videos?

Comment: You could probably Google those terms you want and find something easily. I remember I used to use [Freesound](https://www.freesound.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There are many people who generously donate their time and money to creating music that they provide royalty free. (See list below) You do not have to pay any money to use these tracks, but you do have to provide attribution in the content you create. For example on YouTube, you would put:

> Music: www.freemusicsite.com

Here is a list of three sites I use often for my content:

> [Incompetech](http://incompetech.com/) 
>   [Purple Planet Music](http://www.purple-planet.com/) 
>  www.bensound.com (Sorry Can't do more than three links)

Answer (score 0):

ccMixter is a place where artists upload, build on, sample and remix music using the easy-to-understand "Creative Commons" licensing system.

[dig.ccMixter](http://dig.ccmixter.org/) lets video producers browse through ready-to-use music by tag (so you can look for just "instrumental" or "rock" or "piano" or whatever suits your video).

The "Creative Commons" licensing system means you can tell straight away what permissions that the artist has given you. For example:

- **CC:BY-NC** means you can use it in *non-commercial* videos, as long as you give suitable attribution
- **CC:BY** means you can use it *even in commercial videos*, as long as you give suitable attribution

You can always ask the artist for other permissions, but the Creative Commons sticker shows you what the artist has already given you.

(FYI, these Creative Commons licenses are everywhere, not just at ccMixter -- they apply to more than just music, too.)

Comment: How can one find music that does not require attribution for commercial use? This is a small project not worth spending money for music. But nonetheless attribution of the musical source would distract from the video's primary message. This would need to be addressed in order for this question to be truly answered.

Comment: Some artists use the "CC0" badge to indicate that they grant any and all permissions for any kind of use (aka "no rights reserved"). Many works on ccMixter are [tagged with CC0](http://dig.ccmixter.org/tags/cczero), so you can find them easily.

Answer (score -1):

You might find something suitable in the [Internet Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Archive), which is "a non-profit library of millions of free books, movies, software, music, and more." It is located at [archive.org](http://archive.org).